# Sleuth TraceId IllegalArgumentException Exception

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-sleuth

Encountering the below exception, when using Sleuth along with Spring Boot

The Stack trace is as follows :

ZipkinHttpSpanExtractor.joinTrace 51 : Exception occurred while trying to extract span from carrier java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can't convert empty hex string to long at org.springframework.util.Assert.hasText(Assert.java:181) at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.Span.hexToId(Span.java:583) at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.ZipkinHttpSpanExtractor.buildParentSpan(ZipkinHttpSpanExtractor.java:91) at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.ZipkinHttpSpanExtractor.joinTrace(ZipkinHttpSpanExtractor.java:49) at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.ZipkinHttpSpanExtractor.joinTrace(ZipkinHttpSpanExtractor.java:19)

Using Sprint Boot version is 1.5.3 and spring-cloud-sleuth-core/1.3.1

Any pointers on the fix would be helpful... Thanks in advance.

Comment: You didn't provide enough information to help you. Can you please add some code and explain what you are trying to do?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: We have a gateway service, which listens to the client requests. From the past month, the logs are filled with the above exception. The logging is continuous with the  IllegalArgumentException. We have not made any code changes for the Sleuth code with respect to Trace or Span issues. The Exception is not noticed in our other services. cc: @SimonMartinelli